# 11ty error TypeError: eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy is not a function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, eleventy

I am trying to add my css and javascript codes to 11ty. I learned that 11ty has something called .11ty.js, so i tried using the `addPassthroughCopy()` function.

Here is the script:

```
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("data/mainStyle.css");
    return
        dir: {
            passthroughFileCopy: true
        }
};
```

I tried to use the npx @11ty/eleventy compile, but I got this error message:

```
[11ty] Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
[11ty] 1. Having trouble rendering 11ty.js template ./.11ty.js (via TemplateContentRenderError)
[11ty] 2. eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy is not a function (via TypeError)
[11ty]
[11ty] Original error stack trace: TypeError: eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy is not a function
[11ty]     at module.exports [as render] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\website\.11ty.js:2:20)
[11ty]     at JavaScript.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Engines\JavaScript.js:144:43)
[11ty]     at Template._render (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateContent.js:507:28)
[11ty]     at async Template.renderWithoutLayout (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Template.js:456:27)
[11ty]     at async TemplateMap.populateContentDataInMap (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateMap.js:585:39)
[11ty]     at async TemplateMap.cache (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateMap.js:479:5)
[11ty]     at async TemplateWriter._createTemplateMap (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateWriter.js:330:5)
[11ty]     at async TemplateWriter.generateTemplates (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateWriter.js:360:5)
[11ty]     at async TemplateWriter.write (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateWriter.js:407:23)
[11ty]     at async Eleventy.executeBuild (C:\Users\User\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Eleventy.js:1160:13)
[11ty] Wrote 0 files in 0.04 seconds (v2.0.0)
```

I tried to remove the eleventyconfig.addpassthroughcopy and it worked, but I still need to add the css to my script, can anyone help me out?

I tried to use the eleventyconfig.passthroughcopy, and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

In 11ty 2.0 you are useing - according to the error message - no need to do return statment in this simple case. Also may be your path to the css file is not correct.
For best practice put your css files to a subdirectory named "css" than
try the following:

```
// eleventy.js

module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  // Default output directory: _site

  // Copy 'css/' to '_site/css'
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("css");
};
```

I recomment to use the up to date version of 11ty. You can find the options about passthroughcopy here: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/copy/

Comment: forgot to answer this question lmao, the reason was that i wrote .11ty.js instead of .eleventy.js, that was the reason for the error

Answer (score 0):

forgot to respond with an answer lol. the reason for the bug was that i wrote .11ty.js instead of .eleventy.js, if anybody has a similar issue, just check your spelling and read the documentation carefully